# Случайно заполнить двумерный массив с определенным процентом заполнения

Tags: javascript, массивы, reactjs, случайные-числа, статистика

Как заполнить двумерный массив данными с указанным процентом заполнения?

Например, имеется массив 10*10, в нем необходимо заполнить 30% ячеек, следовательно, 30 ячеек будут содержать данные, 70 будут пустыми.

Задача возникла в результате решения другой, более крупной задачи, поэтому весь код публикую ниже. Метод-генератор массива - `generateData`

Имею три решения.

**Первое решение** - рекурсивно вызывать функцию, которая обходит массив и постепенно заполняет пустые ячейки данными. Начинаем с нулевого элемента массива, если не достигли числа заполнения, снова вызываем функцию. Недостаток - сам рекурсивный подход не очень хорош и заполненные ячейки сбиваются у одной стороны. Возможное решение - по достижению конца массива начинать обход в обратную сторону

```js
const getStyle = style => Object.assign({}, style);

const universeStyle = length => ({
  position: "relative",
  width: `${length * 10}px`,
  height: `${length * 10}px`,
  fontSize: "0",
  border: "1px solid #222"
});

const cellStyle = item => ({
  background: `${item.color}`,
  display: "inline-block",
  boxSizing: "border-box",
  width: "10px",
  height: "10px"
  //border: "1px solid grey"
});

const settingsStyle = () => ({
  margin: "10px 0 0 0"
});

const Cell = ({ item }) => (
  <div x={item.x} y={item.y} style={getStyle(cellStyle(item))} />
);

class Universe extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={getStyle(universeStyle(this.props.width))}>
        {this.props.data.map(item => item.map(item => <Cell item={item} />))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Settings extends React.Component {  
  render() {
    const {fill} = this.props;
    
    return (
      <div style={getStyle(settingsStyle())}>
        <button onClick={() => this.props.generateUniverse()}>Generate</button>
        <div>
          <input
            onChange={event => this.props.setFill(event)}
            type="range"
            value={fill} />
          <span>{fill}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      )
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      fill: 30
    };
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.generateUniverse()
  }
  
  getColor(colors = ['white', 'black']) {
    return colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
  }

  generateData(width, fill) {
    const count = (width * width * fill) / 100;
    const getColor = this.getColor;
    let current = 0;
    const spaceData = Array.from({ length: width }).map((item, y) =>
        Array.from({ length: width }).map((item, x) => 
          ({y: y, x: x, color: 'white'})
      ))
    
    function fillData(data) {
      if (current < count) {
        data.forEach((line, y, data) => 
          line.forEach((obj, x, line) => {
            if (current < count) {
              obj.color = getColor();
              obj.color === 'black' ? current++ : null;
            } else { return data }
          })
        )        
        
        return fillData(data)
      }      
      
      return data
    }
    
    return fillData(spaceData)
  }
  
  generateUniverse() {
    this.setState({
        data: this.generateData(this.props.width, this.state.fill)
      });
  }
  
  redrawUniverse() {
    const idRedraw = setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        data: this.generateData(this.props.width)
      }, this.redrawUniverse);
    }, 500);
    
    this.idRedraw = idRedraw;
  }
  
  stopRedraw() {
    clearTimeout(this.idRedraw)
  }
  
  setFill(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value)
    this.setState({fill: event.target.value})
  }
  
  render() {
    const [{width}, {data, fill}] = [this.props, this.state];
    
    return (
      <div>
        <Universe
          width={width}
          data={data}
        />
        <Settings
          fill={fill}
          setFill={(event) => this.setFill(event)}
          stopRedraw={() => this.stopRedraw()}
          startRedraw={() => this.redrawUniverse()}
          generateUniverse={() => this.generateUniverse()}
        />
      </div>
      )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App width={10} />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

**Второе решение** - случайно генерировать координаты X,Y каждой точки, если искомая точка в массиве уже заполнена - пропускать, если нет - заполнять. Процесс повторять пока массив не достигнет заполнения. Недостаток - на больших процентах заполнения, мы будем иметь мало пустых точек и программа будет тратить больше времени на поиск пустого значения

```js
const getStyle = style => Object.assign({}, style);

const universeStyle = length => ({
  position: "relative",
  width: `${length * 10}px`,
  height: `${length * 10}px`,
  fontSize: "0",
  border: "1px solid #222"
});

const cellStyle = item => ({
  background: `${item.color}`,
  display: "inline-block",
  boxSizing: "border-box",
  width: "10px",
  height: "10px"
});

const settingsStyle = () => ({
  margin: "10px 0 0 0"
});

const Cell = ({ item }) => (
  <div x={item.x} y={item.y} style={getStyle(cellStyle(item))} />
);

class Universe extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={getStyle(universeStyle(this.props.width))}>
        {this.props.data.map(item => item.map(item => <Cell item={item} />))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Settings extends React.Component {  
  render() {
    const {fill} = this.props;
    
    return (
      <div style={getStyle(settingsStyle())}>
        <button onClick={() => this.props.generateUniverse()}>Generate</button>
        <div>
          <input
            onChange={event => this.props.setFill(event)}
            type="range"
            value={fill} />
          <span>{fill}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      )
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      fill: 30
    };
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.generateUniverse();
  }
  
  getRandom(data) {
    return data[Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length)];
  }

  generateData(width, fill) {
    const countFillObj = (width * width * fill) / 100;
    var currentFillObj = 0;
    const getRandom = this.getRandom;
    const arr = Array.from(Array(width).keys());
    const data = Array.from({ length: width }).map((item, y) =>
        Array.from({ length: width }).map((item, x) => 
          ({y: y, x: x, color: 'white'})
      ))
    
    if (fill === 100) {
      return Array.from({ length: width }).map((item, y) =>
        Array.from({ length: width }).map((item, x) => 
          ({y: y, x: x, color: 'black'})
      ))
    } 
    
    while (currentFillObj < countFillObj) {
      var [randomX, randomY] = [getRandom(arr), getRandom(arr)];
      var currentObj = data[randomX][randomY];
      
      if (currentObj.color === 'white') {
        currentObj.color = 'black'; 
        currentFillObj += 1
      } 
    }   
      
    return data
    
  }
  
  generateUniverse() {
    this.setState({
        data: this.generateData(this.props.width, this.state.fill)
      });
  }
  
  redrawUniverse() {
    const idRedraw = setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        data: this.generateData(this.props.width)
      }, this.redrawUniverse);
    }, 500);
    
    this.idRedraw = idRedraw;
  }
  
  stopRedraw() {
    clearTimeout(this.idRedraw)
  }
  
  setFill(event) {
    this.setState({fill: event.target.value});
    this.generateUniverse();
  }
  
  render() {
    const [{width}, {data, fill}] = [this.props, this.state];
    
    return (
      <div>
        <Universe
          width={width}
          data={data}
        />
        <Settings
          fill={fill}
          setFill={(event) => this.setFill(event)}
          stopRedraw={() => this.stopRedraw()}
          startRedraw={() => this.redrawUniverse()}
          generateUniverse={() => this.generateUniverse()}
        />
      </div>
      )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App width={10} />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

**Третье решение** - появилось пока писал вопрос, можно поробовать ввести поправочный коэффициент в вероятность заполнения. И при обходе массива, при заполнении/пропуске точки, вероятность заполнения/пропуска следующих точек изменяется.

Поделитесь, пожалуйста, идеями

Comment: Двумерный массив прекрасно линеаризуется: `a(x,y) => b(x*n+y)` и соответственно де-линеаризуется. Так что фактически задача сводится к генерации заданного количества (z%) неповторяющихся случайных целых чисел в заданном диапазоне, а это очень стандартная задача.

Comment: @Akina не понял ответа. мне не нужны случайные числа. нужно 1 или 0.

Comment: Ну ты вчитайся, да... случайные числа тебе дают "координаты" очередной единички в массиве.

Comment: @Akina "вчитайтесь" в второе решение... как раз случайно генерирую координаты. там же указал недостаток такого решения. есть ссылки на решение "стандартной" задачи?

Comment: 1) Случайная генерация координат по отдельности может упереться в "особенности" генератора, что даст кластерное распределение; 2) Вы сами указываете на проблемы повторного попадания в один и тот же элемент.

Comment: @Akina я не математик, поэтому не учитываю многих вещей и пытаюсь сделать в лоб. что значит `n` в формуле `a(x,y) => b(x*n+y)` в вашем первого комментарии

Comment: ну раз целевой массив 10*10, то n=10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо подсчитывать количество уже заполненных клеток, и на основе него вычислять вероятность заполнения очередной.

Примерно так:

```
var k = n * n * 0.3, // оставшееся количество заполненных клеток
    r = n * n; // оставшееся количество клеток
for (var i = 0; i<n; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j<n; j++) {
    if (Math.random() < k/r) {
      a[i][j] = 1;
      k--;
    } else {
      a[i][j] = 0;
    }
    r--;
  }
}
```

Этот алгоритм делает все возможные варианты заполнения равновероятными.

Comment: да, спасибо! на первый взгляд то, что нужно. все оказалось довольно просто. есть недостатки?

Comment: @while1pass да вроде нет.

Answer (score -1):

Простой, хоть и не лучший, алгоритм.

1. Создаём временный двумерный массив tmp(n * m - 1, 1). По первому измерению количество равно количеству элементов конечного массива n * m, по второму - 2.
2. tmp(i,0) = i; tmp(i,1) = rand();
3. Сортируем по второму измерению.
4. Берём нужный процент первых элементов, по значению первого измерения определяем координаты (x = tmp(i,0)\n, y = tmp(i,0)%n) и ставим единичку (array(x,y)=1).
5. Done.

Comment: Сортировка одна из самых ресурсозатратных операций. На 3 пункте не понятно, что сортируем и зачем? что к этому моменту представляет массив?

Comment: Да, затратно. Но при 100 элементах (и скорее всего интерактивной работе) это не так важно. В п. 3 сортируем по рандомному значению.